# ModbusTcpClient Connection is closed unexpectedly within a ROS application

Tags: multithreading, callback, ros, pymodbus

In this example script, the modbus connection works properly when I call the service the first time, but it is closed unexpectedly when I call the service the second time, raising the following error:

> Error processing request: Modbus Error: [Connection]
> ModbusTcpClient({ip}): Connection unexpectedly closed 0.000089 seconds
> into read of 8 bytes without response from unit before it closed
> connection

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rospy from pymodbus.client.sync
import ModbusTcpClient 
from std_srvs.srv import Empty

driver = ModbusTcpClient("ip", port)

def srv_cb(req):
    status = driver.read_holding_registers(0, 4).registers
    print(status)

def close():
    driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    node_name = 'node'
    rospy.init_node(node_name)

    serv  = rospy.Service('srv', Empty, srv_cb)
    rospy.on_shutdown(close)
    rospy.spin()
```

Could someone help me to understand what is happening?

Comment: What version of pymodbus are you using.

Comment: @Sanju I'm using pymodbus 2.5.1

Comment: If you are receiving an error message on the first read, try using pymodbus `2.5.2` and use the keyword arg `reset_socket=False` in client initialization to see if that can fix the issue.

Comment: I tried with driver = ModbusTcpClient("ip", port, reset_socket=False) but it is not working for me

Comment: Maybe should I try asynchronous client?

Comment: @Sanju The most strange is that when I call the service the first time the connection works properly, the second time, error arises, the third goes well again, the fourth error, and so on.

Comment: It looks your slave is not happy with frequent connection and disconnections, try adding some sleep between calls.